# How to structure this data? JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

```
0:{region: "1", id: "1P1", P1: "7", quantity: 12, multiSum: 84, …}
1:{region: "1", id: "1P2", P2: "7", quantity: 25, multiSum: 175, …}
2:{region: "1", id: "1P3", P3: "7", quantity: 44, multiSum: 308, …}
3:{region: "1", id: "1P4", P4: "7", quantity: 66, multiSum: 462, …}
4:{region: "1", id: "1P5", P5: "7", quantity: 99, multiSum: 693, …}
5:{region: "1", id: "1P6", P6: "7", quantity: 9, multiSum: 63, …}
6:{region: "3", id: "3P1", P1: "8", quantity: 102, multiSum: 816, …}
7:{region: "3", id: "3P2", P2: "8", quantity: 212, multiSum: 1696, …}
8:{region: "3", id: "3P3", P3: "7", quantity: 244, multiSum: 1708, …}
9:{region: "3", id: "3P4", P4: "6", quantity: 964, multiSum: 5784, …}
10:{region: "3", id: "3P5", P5: "4", quantity: 894, multiSum: 3576, …}
11:{region: "3", id: "3P6", P6: "1", quantity: 904, multiSum: 904, …}
```

Hey there, I am having trouble structuring this data. What I would like to do is to loop through the data and create an object[region] with all data that belongs to that region.

To visualize:

```
    ["1": {P1: 7, P2: 7: P3: 7,..., quantity1: 12, quantity2: 25,...},
"3": {P1: 8, P2: 8: P3: 7,..., quantity1: 102, quantity2: 212,...}]
```

This is data from userInputs, hence the repetition. I would appreciate any help.

Thanks!

Comment: What's the initial data type? Is it an object of objects, or an array of objects?

Comment: Array of objects

Comment: Neither the data you got nor the data you want to get does make sense. There are much better ways to structure the data.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is using the function `reduce` to group regions.

This approach increments by one `quatity` and `multiSum` for each region and assigns the remaining keys to the grouped region.

Finally, this approach removes the helper attribute `counts` which contains the current count of `quantity` and `multiSum`.

*The approach is a little hardcoded because of `quantity` and `multiSum` attributes, however, is a good start to improve it later.*

```js
let arr = [{region: "1", id: "1P1", P1: "7", quantity: 12, multiSum: 84},{region: "1", id: "1P2", P2: "7", quantity: 25, multiSum: 175},{region: "1", id: "1P3", P3: "7", quantity: 44, multiSum: 308},{region: "1", id: "1P4", P4: "7", quantity: 66, multiSum: 462},{region: "1", id: "1P5", P5: "7", quantity: 99, multiSum: 693},{region: "1", id: "1P6", P6: "7", quantity: 9, multiSum: 63},{region: "3", id: "3P1", P1: "8", quantity: 102, multiSum: 816},{region: "3", id: "3P2", P2: "8", quantity: 212, multiSum: 1696},{region: "3", id: "3P3", P3: "7", quantity: 244, multiSum: 1708},{region: "3", id: "3P4", P4: "6", quantity: 964, multiSum: 5784},{region: "3", id: "3P5", P5: "4", quantity: 894, multiSum: 3576},{region: "3", id: "3P6", P6: "1", quantity: 904, multiSum: 904}],
    knownKeys = ['region', 'id', 'multiSum', 'quantity'],
    result;
    
Object.values(result = arr.reduce((a, c) => {
  if (!a[c.region]) a[c.region] = {counts: {multiSum: 0, quantity: 0}};
  
  let counts = a[c.region].counts;    
  Object.assign(a[c.region], {[`quantity${counts.quantity += 1}`]: c.quantity, [`multiSum${counts.multiSum += 1}`]: c.multiSum});    
    
  Object.keys(c).forEach(k => {
    if (!knownKeys.includes(k)) Object.assign(a[c.region], {[k]: c[k]});
  });
  
  return a;
}, {})).forEach(v => delete v.counts);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could structure this as an array of objects, and then iterate over it by index or using by `for..of`:

```js
let arr = [
  {region: "1", id: "1P1", P1: "7", quantity: 12, multiSum: 84},
  {region: "1", id: "1P2", P2: "7", quantity: 25, multiSum: 175},
  {region: "1", id: "1P3", P3: "7", quantity: 44, multiSum: 308},
  {region: "1", id: "1P4", P4: "7", quantity: 66, multiSum: 462},
  {region: "1", id: "1P5", P5: "7", quantity: 99, multiSum: 693},
  {region: "1", id: "1P6", P6: "7", quantity: 9, multiSum: 63}
]

for (obj of arr) {
  console.log(obj);
  // do whatever data manipulation you need based on obj.region here
}
```

Or you could structure it as an object, and iterate over it by object key:

```js
let obj = {
  0: {region: "1", id: "1P1", P1: "7", quantity: 12, multiSum: 84},
  1: {region: "1", id: "1P2", P2: "7", quantity: 25, multiSum: 175},
  2: {region: "1", id: "1P3", P3: "7", quantity: 44, multiSum: 308},
  3: {region: "1", id: "1P4", P4: "7", quantity: 66, multiSum: 462},
  4: {region: "1", id: "1P5", P5: "7", quantity: 99, multiSum: 693},
  5: {region: "1", id: "1P6", P6: "7", quantity: 9, multiSum: 63}
}

for (key in obj) {
  console.log(obj[key])
  // do whatever data manipulation you need based on obj[key].region here
}
```

Which is better depends on the data, and what you intend to do with it.  If the keys are meaningful, and you need to be able to access specific individual elements by key, then an object is probably better; if the keys are just sequential numbers as you've shown here, and have no other significance, then you probably would be better off with a plain array.

(There are many, many other ways of iterating over either an array or an object's keys; these are just two examples.)